# Converting SQL pivot table to T-SQL for Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I've been having a spot of bother importing a rather long-winded SQL pivot table dataset into SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 in a format which allows me to add parameter to the report outcome. I understand that this requires the query to be T-SQL friendly

The context is, in case it helps, is that i'm building a report to give a view over various market research panel's eligibility statuses, and i'd like to be able to present a drop down menu to let users flick between panels. So the end `@parameter` will be on `PanelCode` / `PanelName`. It's a composite query:

```
SELECT

    ELT.PanelCode,
    ELR.PanelName,
    ELR.Year,
    ELT.PeriodType,
    ELT.PeriodValue,
    ELT.TotalPanelists,
    ELT.EligiblePanelists,
    ELR.TotalEligible,
    ELR.TotalVacation,
    ELR.TotalExcused,
    ELR.TotalInactive,
    ELR.TotalConnection,
    ELR.TotalCompliance

FROM  --the Ineligibility Reason Pivot Table (ELR)
    (SELECT
        PanelCode,
        PanelName,
        Year,
        PeriodType,
        PeriodValue,
        Max([Eligible]) as TotalEligible,
        Max([Vacation]) as TotalVacation,
        Max([Excuse]) as TotalExcused,
        Max([Inactive]) as TotalInactive,
        Max([Connection]) as TotalConnection,
        Max([Compliance]) as TotalCompliance

FROM

(SELECT 
    PanelCode,
    PanelName,
    Year,
    PeriodType,
    PeriodValue,
    EligibilityFailureReason,

    FROM FullPanellistEligibilityView) FPR

Pivot
    (count(EligibilityFailureReason) FOR EligibilityFailureReason IN ([Eligible], [Vacation], [Excuse], [Inactive], [Connection], [Compliance])) AS PVT


WHERE PeriodType <> '4 week period' and Year > 2012

GROUP BY PanelCode, PanelName, PeriodType, Year, PeriodValue) as ELR


,    -- And the Eligibility Totals Query, ELT
    (
    SELECT
        PanelCode,
        PanelName,
        Year,
        PeriodType,
        PeriodValue,
        Count(Poll1s) as TotalPanelists,
        Sum(Poll1s) as EligiblePanelists


FROM

    (SELECT 
        PanelCode,
        PanelName,
        Year
        PeriodType,
        PeriodValue,
        CAST(isEligible as INT) as Poll1s 


        FROM FullPanellistEligibilityView) FPR

      GROUP BY PanelCode, PeriodType, PeriodValue) ELT

WHERE (ELT.PeriodValue=ELR.PeriodValue) and (ELT.PanelCode=ELR.PanelCode)
```

I've been really struggling to find resources online which suggest how to take larger queries and make them Parameter-able in Report Builder 3. What do I need to add in addition to `WHERE PanelName = @PanelName` to make this run?

EDIT1: I don't doubt that I've made this query far more complicated than necessary, i'm self-teaching. The schema isn't really necessary as all this data is pulled from one single, already existing view, `FullPanellistEligibilityView`, sample data, stripped down and mocked up from the view,  [can be found here](https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__www.filehosting.org_file_details_620980_EligibilityTableTestData2411.csv&d=DgMCaQ&c=zdK58V2JKULZdB8nuBRpog&r=nRR1CFPO9mrxmo9NomWLicrKbR2qHLroPiSl17UStNxIvaY2kkhEsIIcTyvMu2Zq&m=9fVQmi4nzerZFryYz5LhUmRlZxAL1ZJAc9zcpjqe5SU&s=oc50L1WrNMAmSi2rBUjydGGdJmMCoFa3MUOhT9zNae8&e=)

Comment: Can you please post the schema and some test data `FullPanellistEligibilityView`?  This actually looks like a very simple query that has been made a lot more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do in order to set up a data driven parameter selection.

Firstly, you need to create a dataset to populate your parameter drop down menu.  This needs to list all the values you want your user to be able to select, in the correct order.  This can return a column each for the Label shown to the user and the value passed to the query:

```
select distinct PanelCode       -- Parameter Value
                ,PanelName      -- Parameter Label
from FullPanellistEligibilityView
order by PanelName
```

Create a Parameter and set the available values to this dataset, with the appropriate column used for the `Label` and `Value` properties.

Secondly, you need to add a filter to your dataset.  I have taken the liberty of re-writing your query above to use a derived table/common table expression/cte instead of your `PIVOT`.  The code below includes the reference to the SSRS parameter which will insert the 'Value' for the parameter once selected.  This code is obviously not tested as I don't have your schema, but the design should be easy enough to understand:

```
with t
as
(
    select PanelCode
            ,PeriodValue
            ,count(isEligible) as TotalPanelists    -- I'm assuming this is a BIT column, in which case it shouldn't have any null values.  If it does, you will need to handle this with count(isnull(isEligible,0))
            ,Sum(CAST(isEligible as INT)) as EligiblePanelists
    from FullPanellistEligibilityView
    where PanelCode = @PanelCode                    -- This will filter your data due to the INNER JOIN below.
    group by PanelCode
            ,PeriodType
            ,PeriodValue

)
select e.PanelCode
        ,e.PanelName
        ,e.Year
        ,e.PeriodType
        ,e.PeriodValue
        ,t.TotalPanelists
        ,t.EligiblePanelists
        ,sum(case when e.EligibilityFailureReason = 'Eligible' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalEligible,
        ,sum(case when e.EligibilityFailureReason = 'Vacation' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalVacation,
        ,sum(case when e.EligibilityFailureReason = 'Excuse' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalExcused,
        ,sum(case when e.EligibilityFailureReason = 'Inactive' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalInactive,
        ,sum(case when e.EligibilityFailureReason = 'Connection' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalConnection,
        ,sum(case when e.EligibilityFailureReason = 'Compliance' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalCompliance
from FullPanellistEligibilityView e
    inner join t
        on(e.PanelCode = t.PanelValue
            and e.PeriodValue = t.PeriodValue
            )
where e.PeriodType <> '4 week period'
    and e.Year > 2012
group by e.PanelCode
        ,e.PanelName
        ,e.Year
        ,e.PeriodType
        ,e.PeriodValue
        ,t.TotalPanelists
        ,t.EligiblePanelists
```

Comment: That's awesome, already a lot clearer, I need to dash off now but will test this on Monday. Thanks Dave!

Comment: @I'mInWayOverMyHead  No worries!  What you will need to watch out for is that neither yours nor my query handle Panels that have ***no*** eligible Panelists.  In that case the Panel would simply not be returned.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this has done the trick. I've primarily worked in Microsoft Access in the past and so I need to rethink the way I stack queries in order to get the desired output.